# pip install pep-508-url-deps fail

Tags: python, pip, ssl-certificate

i change the index-url, but if i install `pep-508-url-deps`, it is Collecting  `https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/archive/master.zip`, what is happen?

```
(test-3-9) [root@localhost pip]# pip install pep-508-url-deps
Looking in indexes: http://mirrors.tools.douban.com/pypi/simple
Collecting pep-508-url-deps
  Downloading http://mirrors.tools.douban.com/pypi/packages/bc/69/b088a665f2cf87cb1f260376dce6895bf4b00336736b2082ef5af5a8bd20/pep-508-url-deps-1.0.0.post0.tar.gz (1.1 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting sampleproject@ https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/archive/master.zip
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /pypa/sampleproject/archive/master.zip
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /pypa/sampleproject/archive/master.zip
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /pypa/sampleproject/archive/master.zip
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /pypa/sampleproject/archive/master.zip
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /pypa/sampleproject/archive/master.zip
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypa/sampleproject/archive/master.zip (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

when i install numpy, it is ok, It's confusing to me.

```
(test-3-9) [root@localhost pip]# pip install numpy
Looking in indexes: http://mirrors.tools.douban.com/pypi/simple
Collecting numpy
  Downloading http://mirrors.tools.douban.com/pypi/packages/f8/ea/ff38168d6565a8549f819699cac4d89bbc38fc5b27fb94f8e92bcd713348/numpy-1.23.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (17.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 17.1/17.1 MB 19.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.23.2
(test-3-9) [root@localhost pip]#
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

oh, my god, it is must be set `codeload.github.com` and `github.com`  in the field `trusted-host = codeload.thub.com github.com` in the pip.conf.

i only set one of both before.